# Globalize3 english translations in posts or post_translations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, globalize3

I have an existing site with fields in post.title and post.body. After I installed Globalize3, post.title returns blank. Is there a way that I don't need to migrate the existing information to post_translations?

Answer (score 0):

You can migrate this data by defining it to migrate the data when creating the translations table in the first place.

eg.

```
class TranslatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    Post.create_translation_table!({
      :title => :string,
      :text => :text
    }, {
      :migrate_data => true
    })
  end
  def self.down
    Post.drop_translation_table! :migrate_data => true
  end
end
```

You will have to drop the existing posts translations table beforehand.

Comment: I did this did several times, but the English title and text don't copy over to post_translations.  I'm not sure that they should.  The gem seems to be installed correctly, since records can be added to post_translations.  Is the :en local title and body supposed to be in the post table or the post_translations table.  I would like the :en title and body to remains in the posts table and only foreign non-english languages to be in post_translations.  Is there an option for this in Globalize3.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I was having same issue.
Found that for :migrate_data => true to work you need to have your globalize3 version 0.1.0.beta
otherwise it won't work.

You can checkout this - https://github.com/svenfuchs/globalize3/issues/45